# Mysql COUNT VS num rows performance

Tags: mysql, performance, count, rows

I want to select the amount of forum posts compared to a list of users. So it will look like this:
**USERID --- FORUMPOSTS**
3647 - 2
7467 - 14
2673 - 39
3224 - 5
... and so on

Now I'm asking if it would be faster to count the forum post via COUNT(*) or looping through the userlist before and creating a new query for each user to count his/her forum posts via mysql_num_rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let SQL do the grouping and counting

```
select userid, count(*) as forumposts
from your_table
group by userid
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'm asking if it would be faster to count the forum post via COUNT(*) or looping through the userlist before and creating a new query for each user to count his/her forum posts via mysql_num_rows.

It'll be faster to do the former, "count the forum post via COUNT(*)".  You can group the results as follows:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY userid
```

It'll be even faster still if your table has an index on the `userid` column.